# PHP Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-wall

Aarg, can't find a good answer to this question:
How can I auto-login on Facebook (knowing the username/password from a user) and then post a message on the wall? I already downloaded facebook.php, base_facebook.php and other files, but I don't how I can get this working...

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create a facebook app. This will give you the appId and secret that are required to do most things with the graph api.

You don't even need the username and password of the user, they can authorise your app to post to their wall.

You can find all the info https://developers.facebook.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the facebook graph api and oauth to post on the facebook wall of a user.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook's API does not support authentication via a user's email and password. You don't need facebook.php, or base_facebook.php. What you need is PHP and cURL to mimic browser HTTP requests and login to Facebook *manually*.

Try logging in to http://m.facebook.com and use Firefox's [Firebug Addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) or Chrome's [Developer Tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/network.html) to monitor browser requests.